# Saving an Object for use later

Tags: android

As part of my widget, I use an instance of the Camera object.

This is what I want to do.  The user will click on my widget, I get an instance of the Camera(if it's not already stored), use it, then store it.  If they click the widget again, I want to use that same instance that I used previously.

Is this possible?

**EDITED**:  I can't release the Camera(`android.hardware.Camera`) until the user clicks on the widget the second time.  So the user clicks on the widget the first time, I get the camera and hold on to it until they click the widget again.

The problem I am running into is on the second click, I am trying to get the Camera again, which I can't because I currently have it in use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I figured this out, I think.

If I make a static class object for the widget class, it seems to keep it in memory.

`private static Camera camera = null;`

Then setting it in code..

`camera = Camera.open();`

does seem to keep it in memory for use later.  I don't know if that's really inefficient or not, but that's the only way I could get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible for an app widget to "store" arbitrary objects.

If the "Camera" object is `android.hardware.Camera`, you should be using it and releasing it as soon as you are done, anyway, so other applications can use the camera.

Comment: I can't release the camera until the user clicks on the widget the second time.  Is there any other way of handling this?

Comment: @Eclipsed4utoo: I am interpreting that you really are meaning `android.hardware.Camera`. In that case, what you want is impossible several times over -- not only can you not hold onto a `Camera` (as noted above), but you need a `SurfaceView` for the camera preview, which is not possible with an app widget. You are welcome to use the `Camera` with an `Activity`.

Comment: I am talking about that camera, but I am not using the SurfaceView(and don't need it).

Comment: @Eclipsed4utoo: The `Camera` will not work without a `SurfaceView` and an active preview, AFAIK, so the user knows the camera is in operation.

Comment: I am doing this for the flash, so no SurfaceView is needed.  The user knows that it's using the camera. I figured it out though.